# A question about ideal class number

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

**The question is**:What is the ideal class number of field $K:=\mathbb{Q}(m)$? Here $m$ satisfy the equation $m^3+m+1=0$.

Maybe we should find the Minkowski constant $M(K)$ firstly, but I do not know how to find $d(K)$ and the following up for this example. It looks different from examples I calculated. The solution of this equation is weird. So I hope we can have some details.

What is more, I think it is a difficult question about calculating the ideal class number of a random field, what kind of fields' class number we have known?

Appreciating for any suggestion.

Comment: First calculate the discriminant of the order $\Bbb{Z}[m]$, which is the discriminant of the cubic polynomial $m^3+m+1$. Then the discriminant of the true integer ring in $K$ will divide this and the ratio will be a square. In particular, if the discriminant of $\Bbb{Z}[m]$ is square free, then the integer ring will just be $\Bbb{Z}[m]$ itself. The formula for the discriminant of $x^3+px+q$ is $-4p^3-27q^2$, which in this case is $-31$, which is squarefree. Thus $d(K)=-31$.

Comment: @jgon Thank you for your comment. So does $M(K)=\sqrt{31}$? And we need to consider $p=2, 3$ for the next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Minkowski bound is 
$$M(K) = \sqrt{\Delta} \left(\frac 4 \pi\right)^{r_2} \frac{n!}{n^n}$$
For the purposes of computing the class number or group, sometimes just an upper bound on this is enough. There are weaker versions of the Minkowski bound too that can be useful in small number fields as well.

Your cubic is irreducible by the rational root theorem, as you probably knew, so $n=3$.

We know that $\Delta$, the discriminant of the number field is bounded by the discriminant of the minimal polynomial, which is $31$. In this case they are actually equal because the discriminant is squarefree, but in some circumstances you can get away with weakening the bound by just using the discriminant of the polynomial without determining that of the field.

Lastly, $r_2$ is either $1$ or $0$ because $2r_2 + r_1$ is the degree $3$. It happens to actually be $1$, but again without even doing the work to verify that we can just weaken our bound by taking the largest $r_2$ possible and seeing if what we get is reasonable. Alternatively, we can see that the polynomial has no positive roots and at most one negative rule by, for instance, the rule of signs. Since the degree is odd it does have at least one real root, and hence exactly one real root. This leaves us with two complex conjugate roots, so $r_2 = 1$.

Putting all of this together, we see that
$$M(K) \leq \sqrt {31} \left(\frac 4 \pi\right)^1 \frac{3!}{3^3} = \sqrt {31} \frac 4 \pi \frac {2}{9} = \sqrt{31} \frac 8 {9}\frac 1 \pi$$
Clearly $\sqrt {31} \leq 6$ and $\frac 8{9} < 1$ and $\frac 1\pi < \frac 13$ and so the whole thing is *strictly* less than $2$, and therefore the class group is trivial.

Comment: Thank you so much